# angular-translate. What is the best way to implement i18n using json files that are stored on the server, not the client

Tags: json, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

Implementing i18n isn't very difficult when you have a list of json documents stored on the client. But what if you can't have the json files stored locally? They have to be retrieved at runtime. What is the best way to achieve this.

I thought about storing them in sessionStorage as they are required but how do I get angular-translate to work with that or something similar?

When I work with local files I simply point to their location:

```
urlTemplate: 'assets/translation/{lang}/{part}.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but I have been using the static files loader from angular-translate for this.

Let's say you have a folder full of translation files:

```
locales/locale-de_DE.json 
locales/locale-en_GB.json 
locales/locale-nl_BE.json 
...
```

Then in your app, you would do this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);

app.config([ '$translateProvider',
  function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: 'locales/',
      suffix: '.json'
    });
  }
]);

app.run([ '$translate',
  function($translate) {
    // Set default language to German
    $translate.use('locale-de_DE');
  }
]);
```

Whenever you want to switch the language later on in your code, you just need to call the $translate-service with the language you want to switch to, e.g.

```
[...]
$translate.use('locale-en_GB'); // switch to British English
[...]
```

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but I cannot have a folder stored locally. I need to grab the json files from the server at runtime and store them somewhere where they can be accessed globally.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting you, but whenever you call $translate.use(), an XHR-call to the server will be used to load the corresponding JSON file from the server asynchronously.

Additionally, there is the $translateUrlLoader-service (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateUrlLoader). Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: All the examples I have seen all have a folder on the client with en, en-FR etc. I have to load my files from the api. I'm not sure where to store them. A Service, session storage....

Comment: Ah, I see. What I would do then is store translations into session or locale storage as JSON string.

`app.config([ '$translateProvider',
  function($translateProvider) {
    // Load translations from server here and then store them
    var responseEN = { ID_1: 'TEXT_EN_1', ID_2: 'TEXT_EN_2' };
    localeStorage.setItem('translationsEN', JSON.stringify(responseEN));
  }
]);

app.run([ '$translate',
  function($translate) {
    localeStorage.getItem('translationsEN');
    $translate.use('translationsEN');
  }
]);`

Comment: Yes I have also considered doing it this way, however this means I have to translate the entire app as opposed to using add part. I could have static files on the mid tear and point to that but ideally I would have the files mapped to objects so the UI designer knows what to expect.